# Random images on buttons

Tags: vb.net

Good evening made the following code, create an array of buttons and panels, now how do I insert random images to those buttons, can you help me please.

```
    Public Sub crearBotonesPaneles(ByVal creaBoton(,) As Button, ByVal creaPanel As Panel)

    Dim puntoLocacion As Point
    puntoLocacion.X = 20
    puntoLocacion.Y = 40

    For filas As Integer = 0 To 1
        For columnas As Integer = 0 To 3
            If IsNothing(creaBoton(filas, columnas)) Then
                creaBoton(filas, columnas) = New Button
                creaBoton(filas, columnas).Location = puntoLocacion
                creaBoton(filas, columnas).Width = 50
                creaBoton(filas, columnas).Height = 50


                creaPanel.Controls.Add(creaBoton(filas, columnas))
                puntoLocacion.X = puntoLocacion.X + 50


            End If

        Next
        puntoLocacion.X = 20
        puntoLocacion.Y = puntoLocacion.Y + 50
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ...and your random images would be stored and/or located where?

Comment: I have the images in a folder on the pc, they should be seen in the panel

Answer (score 2):

Doing something random ALWAYS means generating one or more random numbers in an appropriate range and then using them in an appropriate manner. The way you determine the range is application-specific and the manner in which you use the number(s) is application-specific. In your case, you might get the paths of all the image files in a folder, use random numbers to order those paths randomly and then use the paths one by one to get the images from the files. E.g.

```vb
Private rng As New Random 'Random number generator
Private imagePaths As Queue(Of String)

Private Sub LoadImagePaths()
    'Create a new queue of file paths sorted based on a random number mapped to each one.
    imagePaths = New Queue(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures,
                                                               "*.jpg").
                                                OrderBy(Function(s) rng.NextDouble()))
End Sub

Private Function GetNextImage() As Image
    'Load the image paths is there is no queue or the current queue is empty.
    If imagePaths?.Any() = False Then
        LoadImagePaths()
    End If

    'Create an image from the next file in the queue.
    Return Image.FromFile(imagePaths.Dequeue())
End Function
```

Based on that code, you just call `GetNextImage` each time you need a random image. There will be no repeats until the entire list is exhausted.